# Strokes is getting deleted while writing

Tags: ipad, stylus, handwriting

When I’m writting with a stylus while keeping my hand on my iPad 6th gen ios 12.1.4, some of the strokes keeps dissapearing

My attempt to resolve

I found solution online suggesting me to turn off magnification feature . But this dint work the issue still persists.

Also this issue happens with Apple Pencil,and many users have complained about this

I tied reaching Apple care people they were of no help.

So how do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this problem and it was caused by part of my hand hitting on the area where I am trying to write. If a finger or side of my hand accidentally comes in touch with screen the corresponding keystroke will not appear.

Comment: Thanks for the answer .I’m sure that iPad support palm rejection, if I dint the part where ur hand touch would also be marked with ink starys but that doesn’t happen you can check it out